# How to change the return value of a method in a unit test mid execution

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net, nsubstitute

I'm trying to design a unit test to test a retry loop pattern. The only way I can think to do this is to change what's returned by the method embedded at the heart of the retry loop half way through the test.

For example... I'd like to throw an exception for a particular method for the first 5 seconds of the test. And then stop that exception from being thrown and actually respond with some valid data after that point.

For the first 5 seconds:

```
service.MethodToRetry(Arg.Any<string>()).ThrowsForAnyArgs(new Exception());
```

And then after that the exception condition is removed and MethodToRetry() completes normally.

Is this possible or am I going about it completely the wrong way? I'm working in c# with xunit and nsubstitute.

Comment: are you using NSubstitute?

Comment: @JoelRamosMichaliszen yes, using NSubstitute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: the tests here are to demonstrate NSubstitute's behaviour. In real tests we wouldn't test a substitute. :)*

One way to test retries is to stub multiple returns (this may not work in your case if you need a condition rather than failing for a specific number of calls, but thought I'd start off with the simplest approach):

```
    [Test]
    public void StubMultipleCalls() {
        Func<string> throwEx = () => { throw new Exception(); };
        var sub = Substitute.For<IThingoe>();
        // Stub method to fail twice, then return valid data
        sub.MethodToRetry(Arg.Any<string>())
           .Returns(x => throwEx(), x => throwEx(), x => "works now");

        // The substitute will then act like this:
        Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => sub.MethodToRetry("")); 
        Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => sub.MethodToRetry("")); 
        Assert.AreEqual("works now", sub.MethodToRetry(""));
        // Will continue returning last stubbed value...
        Assert.AreEqual("works now", sub.MethodToRetry(""));
        Assert.AreEqual("works now", sub.MethodToRetry(""));
    }
```

Another option is to put the condition in while you are stubbing the call:

```
    [Test]
    public void StubWithCondition() {
        var shouldThrow = true;

        var sub = Substitute.For<IThingoe>();
        sub.MethodToRetry(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(x => {
            if (shouldThrow) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            return "works now";
        });

        Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => sub.MethodToRetry(""));
        shouldThrow = false; // <-- can alter behaviour by modifying this variable
        Assert.AreEqual("works now", sub.MethodToRetry(""));
    }
```

As a modified version of this approach, you can also replace the callback used for the stub:

```
    [Test]
    public void ReplaceLambda() {
        Func<string> methodToRetry = () => { throw new Exception(); };

        var sub = Substitute.For<IThingoe>();
        sub.MethodToRetry(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(x => methodToRetry());

        Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => sub.MethodToRetry(""));
        methodToRetry = () => "works now";
        Assert.AreEqual("works now", sub.MethodToRetry(""));
    }
```

Ideally we'd try to avoid timing-dependent logic in tests, but if it is really necessary we could update the condition in the second example after 5 seconds to get the behaviour mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, I don't see any concrete implementations so I'll put it in general.

Thoughts:

1. Because you want to test a "retry loop pattern" I assume you have the logic of the "5 second wait" part. This logic should be an injectable call, so in your test you can check whether it has been called or not. 
   (http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/received-calls/ )
2. The waiting part shouldn't be in your tests because your method have to wait in retry steps not the tests.

Comment: I've looked at this article but I'm struggling to apply it to my particular problem - I need to prove that it will fail temporarily and after a certain condition is met, succeed. This to my involves changing the state of the executed method half way through the test case's execution.

Comment: What do you mean on "fail temporarily"? You mean there are cases when your method will throw an exception internally and in these cases you will return with a different return value?

Comment: I need the method to throw exceptions at the beginning of the test, retry a couple of times and then switch to returning a correct result to validate the retry logic.

Comment: I think I see the point now. So going with #1 thought, you can sub the call to throw an exception and after a given number of calls ( it's just an example, here is the part when your condition changes ) you can change your sub to NOT throw an exception in your test and call your method again.

Comment: that's correct! It doesn't matter what the condition is, I can handle that part. I just need to know how to update a stub method from throwing an exception at the beginning of a test to returning a result at the end.

Comment: There are many options I think:
1. Make an internal property in your class to your dependency, let's say IRetryLogic RetryLogic {get; set;} and apply the InternalsVisibleTo attribute on your library to make it visible to the test assemblies. So it will be a property what you can easily modify in your test.

2. Setup and use an IoC just for testing purposes, so when you need to change the result of your method call, just modify the value of the dependency in your IoC container and in the next run the result of the method call will be different.